Conditional expectation of order statistics when observing ratio/difference
Suppose two independent ordered draws from some continuous and bounded distribution $F_{[0,\bar{x}]}$ with $f>0$ everywhere, represented by the order statistics $$X_{(1:2)}=\min(X_1,X_2)\text{, and }X_{(2:2)}=\max(X_1,X_2).$$ I am interested in these questions:
1.) We observe some realization of the ratio $R=X_{(2:2)}/X_{(1:2)}=r$. How do we calculate the expectations $\mathbb{E}[X_{(2:2)}|R=r]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_{(1:2)}|R=r]$ based on this information?
2.) We observe some realization of the difference $D=X_{(2:2)}-X_{(1:2)}=d$. How do we calculate the expectations $\mathbb{E}[X_{(2:2)}|D=d]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_{(1:2)}|D=d]$ based on this information?

Do you know $\bar x$ or not?  If you don't know it, it would seem that $r$ supplies no information at all.

$\bar{x}$ and the distribution are indeed known.

Now I am completely confused: if the distribution is known, then just calculate the expectations!  Are you instead trying to say $F$ is known to be a member of some family of distributions supported in the interval $[0,\bar x]$?  Is this interval the common support of all those distributions, or do only assume this interval includes all their supports?  What specifically do you assume about this family?

No, that is not what I am trying to say. The distribution is known, and indeed expectations can be calculated. Now if I have additional information, i.e., knowledge that two draws will feature a ratio $r$, or difference $d$, the expectations should be updated accordingly. This conditional Expectation is what I am interested in.

That makes no sense, because when the distribution is known, you don't need any observations at all: you have complete information about the distribution and no matter how many realizations you make of it, you gain no more information.

A concrete example: Let's work in the discrete space. If I roll two dice, the ordered expectations of my draws will be 2 and 4. Suppose someone took a look at the result and said to me the difference is 5. Now, I certainly know the results of my throw, which should be reflected by the conditional expectations being 1 and 6. Well, I don't know how I should transfer this into a general form, but I hope this illustrates the intuition.

I see: you are trying to compute a conditional expectation.  However, that's a calculation, not an "update" of information about the distribution, which is what makes this sound confusing to me.  What is the obstacle to applying the standard formula for conditional expectations?

I do not know how to point out the joint distributions $F_{X_{(i:2)},D}$, or $F_{X_{(i:2)},R}$ .

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_vector

The joint distribution is given in full generality at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511953/order-statistics-with-joint-density/511977#511977 (cc @Jarle)
